# Android kotlin / java - ReclerView strange behavior when hiding parts in holder / xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I didn't know what proper title for this issue could be.

I'm doing a chat app and this is the part inside the adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val msg = messages[position]

    if (msg.who == "you"){
        holder.messagemelayout.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.messageyou.text = msg.message
    }else{
        holder.messageyoulayout.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.messageme.text = msg.message
    }
}
```

So when the message is sent be `me` then the layout for "you" (`messageyoulayout`) get's hidden and vice versa

Not when I add new messages like this:

```
        var count = 1
        bbb.setOnClickListener {
            messageslist.add(Chat("hey " + count.toString(), "me"))
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.itemCount - 1)

            count++
        }
```

The result is this:

[image]

And when I don't hide any layouts then the text inside the layout which don't get any update is still getting filled by random old stuff:

[image]

I hope the issue is understandable.

How can I fix this? Like completely removing the layout which don't get an update or something.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Whole adapter:

```
class ChatAdapter(val context: Context, private val messages: MutableList<Chat>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder>(){


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val msg = messages[position]

        if (msg.who == "you"){
            holder.messageyou.text = msg.message

            holder.messageme.text = ""

            holder.messageme.setBackgroundResource(0)
            holder.messageyou.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corners_lightgray_color)

        }else{
            holder.messageme.text = msg.message

            holder.messageyou.text = ""

            holder.messageme.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corners_accent_color)
            holder.messageyou.setBackgroundResource(0)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = messages.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.chat, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!){

        val messageyou = itemView!!.messageyou!!
        val messageme = itemView!!.messageme!!
        val messageyoulayout = itemView!!.messageyoulayout!!
        val messagemelayout = itemView!!.messagemelayout!!

    }

}
```

chat.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/malsehn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messagemelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messageme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corners_accent_color"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageyoulayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messageyou"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corners_lightgray_color"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You should not be using `if(msg.who == "you")` instead use `if(msg.who.contentEquals("you"))` in your if statement.

Comment: I don't understand what "strange behavior"  you are referring to. There is nothing random about "TextView" and if you do not hide the `View` then it will remain visible.

Comment: The second image just shows that recyclerview is still filling the holder with anything. The main issue is shown in image one. Look at the count and the spacing in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call it bugged mess when you don't understand how ViewHolder pattern works.

You should have used multiple `itemViewType`s instead of flipping views visibility back-to-back (note this entire code goes into your `RecyclerView.Adapter`):

```
// constants
companion object {
    const val TYPE_YOU = 1
    const val TYPE_ME = 2
}

/* This method is called to determine what type of ViewHolder should be used to represent item at [position] */
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = if(messages[position].who == "you") TYPE_YOU else TYPE_ME

/* [viewType] determines what ViewHolder we should create. */
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val layoutId = when(viewType){
        TYPE_YOU -> {
            // this viewholder will display only messages from "you", inflate only "you" layout
            R.layout.chat_item_you
        }
        TYPE_ME ->{
            // this viewholder will display only messages from "me", inflate only "me" layout
            R.layout.chat_item_me
        }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown viewType: $viewType")
    }
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(itemView)
}

// then you can use your original bind method, because "you" and "me" messages will never re-user others ViewHolder
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val msg = messages[position]

    if (msg.who == "you"){
        // holder.itemViewtype should always be equal to TYPE_YOU here
    }else{
        // holder.itemViewtype should always be equal to TYPE_ME here           
    }

    holder.message.text = msg.message
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val txtMessage : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message)
}
```

Then split chat bubbles into two separate layouts:

*chat_item_you.xml*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/message"
         style="@style/ChatBubbleStyle"
         android:background="@drawable/round_corners_lightgray_color"
         android:text="TextView"
         android:layout_gravity="end" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And similar but with other color and gravity:

*chat_item_me.xml*

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/message"
         style="@style/ChatBubbleStyle"
         android:background="@drawable/round_corners_blue_color"
         android:text="TextView"
         android:layout_gravity="start" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Use shared style in *styles.xml* to prevent redundant code:

```
<style name="ChatBubbleStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please explain how to 'inflate only "you" layout'. I will test it tomorrow, done for today.

Comment: @EduardUnruh you did not post your `onCreateViewHolder` (including inflated layout XML) or your `ViewHolder` class so I won't be guessing how to do it.

Comment: But actually a quick example would be enough of how to inflate different layouts so other can use it too, not just me ^^

Comment: @EduardUnruh added some sample code, used simplified layout because I was not sure why You had 8 layouts just to show 1 textview.

Answer (score 0):

After tryng to set width/height of non used holder to 0, removing background and some other stuff which all "worked" but created other strange behaviors I found the only working non bugged solution:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val msg = messages[position]

    if (msg.who == "you"){
        holder.messageyou.text = msg.message

        holder.messageme.text = ""

        holder.messageme.setBackgroundResource(0)
        holder.messageyou.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corners_lightgray_color)

    }else{
        holder.messageme.text = msg.message

        holder.messageyou.text = ""

        holder.messageme.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corners_accent_color)
        holder.messageyou.setBackgroundResource(0)
    }
}
```

Yes you have to define the background on BOTH layouts over and over again and tell the holder that there is nothing to fill where it really isn't. Android is a bugged time wasting mess..